# Monitorar usuários em tempo real IOS

Tags: ios, web-service, objective-c, gps, geolocalização

Alguém saberia me responder qual a melhor forma para obter a localização de um usuário em tempo real através de GPS em IOS, estou com duvida se seria correto eu obter a localização do usuário de 10 em 10 segundos e fazer uma requisição com o Web Service atualizando sua localização, as pessoas irão se movimentar eu tenho que atualizar os usuários no mapa, alguém saberia responder?

Answer (score 2):

Quando você fala "tempo real", você precisa definir precisamente o que é isso. Assumindo que a sua aplicação faça o tracking de vários usuários em algum mapa, se a informação estiver atrasada alguns segundos (ou alguns minutos), isso é um problema? E qual o perfil de movimentação dos usuários - estão normalmente se movendo rapidamente, ou mais devagar? A resposta para essas perguntas vai dizer qual abordagem você deve tomar.

Note que uma abordagem que coleta a informação do GPS a cada segundo (ou menos) e manda a informação pro servidor vai te dar o melhor grau de "tempo real" (assumindo que você tenha alguma lógica no servidor para normalizar as variações do sinal do GPS), mas provavelmente vai consumir tanta bateria do usuário que a tendência é que ele/ela desinstale a aplicação.

Começando com a segunda pergunta (perfil de movimentação do usuário). Se a maioria dos usuários estão se movimentando "devagar" (o que também é um termo relativo - pequenas mudanças de posição são aumentadas se o nível de zoom do mapa que você está usando for alto), você pode esperar mais que 10 segundos para coletar a posição do GPS. Se você sabe que a movimentação é rápida, ou que é possível que o usuário pode não estar se movimentando em linha reta, fazendo várias curvas (por exemplo, uma aplicação de corrida, tipo o RunKeeper), onde , então o intervalo deve ser reduzido (também levando-se em conta que o sinal do GPS tem um erro que deve ser incorporado).

Em relação à primeira pergunta (quão "tempo real" é a informação), se a sua aplicação não precisar da precisão em segundos, você pode demorar mais para atualizar a posição do usuário no web service. Note que isso é ortogonal à captura de dados do GPS - você pode até estar capturando a posição a cada segundo (se for necessário), mas só transmitir para o servidor a cada minuto, por exemplo.

Enfim, como várias perguntas, a resposta é "depende". Você deve coletar dados do GPS tão frequente quanto seja necessário, mas não mais que isso. O mesmo com a atualização de dados no serviço - tão frequente quanto preciso, mas nada além.